# After Azure Deployment I cannot log in

Tags: c#, azure

I want to log in my app https://chatify-uebzqvziqotv9dej.azurewebsites.net/. When I try to log in, I get https://chatify-uebzqvziqotv9dej.azurewebsites.net/api/user/login 500. But it works locally.

I have a problem when I deploy my app. I use DBeaver to look at the table.
DBeaver works when it is local.

[image]

But it doesn't work anymore when I deploy.

[image]

If you need further information, just ask.

I have no idea why it works local but after deployment it doesn't. That's why I don't have any clue how to solve my problem.

Edit: Here is my code for login
ChatifyContext.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using Bogus;
using ChatifyProject.Application.Model;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ChatifyProject.Application.Infrastructure
{
    public class ChatifyContext : DbContext
    {
        

        public ChatifyContext(DbContextOptions<ChatifyContext> opt) : base(opt) { }
        public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();
        public DbSet<Userprofile> Profiles => Set<Userprofile>();

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var key in entityType.GetForeignKeys())
                    key.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;

                foreach (var prop in entityType.GetDeclaredProperties())
                {
                    if (prop.Name == "Guid")
                    {
                        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasAlternateKey("Guid");
                        prop.ValueGenerated = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAdd;
                    }
                    if (prop.ClrType == typeof(string) && prop.GetMaxLength() is null) prop.SetMaxLength(255);
                    if (prop.ClrType == typeof(DateTime)) prop.SetPrecision(3);
                    if (prop.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?)) prop.SetPrecision(3);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the database with some values (holidays, ...).
        /// Unlike Seed, this method is also called in production.
        /// </summary>
        private void Initialize()
        {
            ...
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates random values for testing the application. This method is only called in development mode.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        private void Seed()
        {
            ...
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the database. Called once at application startup.
        /// </summary>
        public void CreateDatabase(bool isDevelopment)
        {
            if (isDevelopment) { Database.EnsureDeleted(); }
            // EnsureCreated only creates the model if the database does not exist or it has no
            // tables. Returns true if the schema was created.  Returns false if there are
            // existing tables in the database. This avoids initializing multiple times.
            if (Database.EnsureCreated()) { Initialize(); }
            if (isDevelopment) Seed();
        }
    }
}
```

UserController.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using ChatifyProject.Application.Dto;
using ChatifyProject.Application.Infrastructure;
using ChatifyProject.Application.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    // DTO class for the JSON body of the login request
    public record CredentialsDto(string username, string password);

    private readonly ChatifyContext _db;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly bool _isDevelopment;

    public UserController(IHostEnvironment _env, IConfiguration config, ChatifyContext db)
    {
        _config = config;
        _isDevelopment = _env.IsDevelopment();
        _db = db;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// POST /api/user/login
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] CredentialsDto credentials)
    {
        var lifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(3);
        var searchuser = _config["Searchuser"];
        var searchpass = _config["Searchpass"];
        var secret = Convert.FromBase64String(_config["Secret"]);
        var localAdmins = _config["LocalAdmins"].Split(",");

        try
        {
            using var service = _isDevelopment && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchuser)
            ? AdService.Login(searchuser, searchpass, credentials.username)
            : AdService.Login(credentials.username, credentials.password);

            var currentUser = service.CurrentUser;
            if (currentUser is null) { return Unauthorized(); }
            //register in login
            var user = await _db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name == credentials.username);
            if (user is null)
            {
                user = new User(credentials.username, credentials.password, currentUser.Email, Userrole.User);
                await _db.Users.AddAsync(user);
                try { await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); }
                catch (DbUpdateException) { return BadRequest(); }
            }
            else if (!user.CheckPassword(credentials.password)) { return Unauthorized(); }

            var role = localAdmins.Contains(currentUser.Cn)
                            ? AdUserRole.Management.ToString() : currentUser.Role.ToString();
            var group = (currentUser.Role, currentUser.Classes.Length > 0) switch
            {
                (AdUserRole.Pupil, true) => currentUser.Classes[0],
                (AdUserRole.Pupil, false) => "Unknown class",
                (AdUserRole.Teacher, _) => AdUserRole.Teacher.ToString(),
                (AdUserRole.Management, _) => AdUserRole.Teacher.ToString(),
                (_, _) => AdUserRole.Administration.ToString()
            };
            if (currentUser.Classes.Length > 0)
            {
                user.Group = currentUser.Classes[0];
            }

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                // Payload for our JWT.
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, currentUser.Cn),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, currentUser.Cn),
                new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role),
                new Claim("Group", group)
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow + lifetime,
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return Ok(new
            {
                Username = currentUser.Cn,
                Role = role,
                Group = group,
                Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
            });
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)  // Catch unknown User or invalid password from AdService
        { return Unauthorized(); }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// GET /api/user/me
    /// Gets information about the current (authenticated) user.
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("me")]
    public IActionResult GetUserdata()
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name;
        return Ok(new
        {
            Username = HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name,
            Group = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Group")?.Value
        });
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpGet("all")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllUsers()
    {
        var user = await _db.Users
            .Select(u => new
            {
                u.Name,
                u.Password,
                u.Email,
                u.Role,
                u.Group
            })
            .ToListAsync();
        if (user is null) { return BadRequest(); }
        return Ok(user);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// POST /api/user/register
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] CredentialsDto credentials)
    {
        var user = await _db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Name == credentials.username);
        if (user != null) { return BadRequest("User already exists"); }
        user = new User(credentials.username, credentials.password, "guest@gmail.com", Userrole.User);
        await _db.Users.AddAsync(user);
        try { await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); }
        catch (DbUpdateException) { return BadRequest("Could not register user"); }
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Login.vue

```
<script setup>
import axios from 'axios';
import signalRService from '../services/SignalRService.js';
</script>

<template>
    <div class="login">
        <template v-if="!username">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="loginModel.username" />
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" v-model="loginModel.password" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" v-on:click="login()">Login</button>
        </template>
        <template v-else> User {{ username }} logged in. <span class="logoutLink" v-on:click="logout()">Logout</span> </template>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.login {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.login input {
    width: 10em;
}
.logoutLink {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
</style>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            loginModel: {
                username: '',
                password: '',
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async login() {
            try {
                const userdata = (await axios.post('user/login', this.loginModel)).data;
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${userdata.token}`;
                this.$store.commit('authenticate', userdata);
                signalRService.configureConnection(userdata.token);
                await signalRService.connect();                
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.response.status == 401) {
                    alert('Login failed. Invalid credentials.');
                }
            }
        },
        logout() {
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
            this.$store.commit('authenticate', null);
        },
    },
    computed: {
        authenticated() {
            return this.$store.state.userdata.username ? true : false;
        },
        username() {
            return this.$store.state.userdata.username;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

SignalRService.js

```
import process from 'node:process'
import * as SignalR from '@microsoft/signalr'

/**
 * SignalRService
 * A facade for the server/client communication over the SignalR protocol.
 */
class SignalRService {
    constructor() {
        this.connected = false;
    }
    configureConnection(token) {
        const host = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? "/chatHub" : "http://localhost:5001/chatHub";
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/hubconnectionbuilder?view=signalr-js-latest
        this.connection = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(`${host}`, { accessTokenFactory: () => token })
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .configureLogging(SignalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();
    } 
    async connect() {
        try {
          if (this.connection.state === SignalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected) {
            await this.connection.start();
            this.connected = true;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Failed to connect to SignalR hub:", error);
          this.connected = false;
          throw error;
        }
      }    
    subscribeEvent(type, callback) {
        this.connection.on(type, callback);
    }
    unsubscribeEvent(type, callback) {
        if (typeof callback === 'undefined')
            this.connection.off(type);
        else
            this.connection.off(type, callback);
    }
    async sendMessageToAll(message, user) {
        if (!this.connected) { throw new Error("Invalid state. Not connected."); }
        // SendMessageToAll is corresponding to the C# Method in SignalR Hub.
        await this.connection.invoke("SendMessageToAll", message, user);
    }
    async requestConnectedUsers() {
        if (!this.connected) { throw new Error("Invalid state. Not connected."); }
        // RequestConnectedUsers is corresponding to the C# Method in SignalR Hub.
        await this.connection.invoke("RequestConnectedUsers");
    }    
}

// Export a singleton (only 1 instance in the spa to make state management easier)
const signalRSerivce = new SignalRService();
export default signalRSerivce;
```